# Switch mysql statements to postgresql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I'm new in php and postgres sql.
I'm trying to switch from mysql to postgresql.

I did that on mysql:

```
$adresse=mysql_escape_string($_POST['mail_user']);
if(isset($_POST['mail_user']))
{
   $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT email FROM newusers2 WHERE email =?');
           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $adresse);
           mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
           mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
  $nb = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
               if ($nb>=1) {
                            //echo "address already exist"
                            $nb == 0;
                            } 
               else {
                            //echo "address added"
                            $nb == 0;
                     }
}
```

And I would like to have your advice about the equivalent in Postgresql.

```
$check = "SELECT email FROM newusers2 WHERE email = $2";
$stmt = pg_query_params($con,$check,array($adresse));
$nb = pg_numrows($stmt);
```

I'll really appreciate your help and all your advices.

Thanks

Comment: a) What's your question b) $2? 2?

Comment: Looks fine  to my non-PHP-using eye except `$2` should be `$1` and you forgot to check for errors (in both cases)

Answer (score 0):

Check out PHP Pear DB module, it's database indifferent and easy to use. Or use the newer module MDB2.